# How to call a variable in a date-command with a set time-zone inside a script

Tags: bash, shell

my current task is to implement a scheduling tool for maintenance-windows.

I want to convert the input start-date and end-date into unix-timestamps and need to implement a convertion from my timezone (Europe/Berlin) to UTC.

I've got the command to work, when a set date is given. For testing purpose I created a small script reading the input (date) from a user and I want to convert the date saved in that variable to be converted, but I struggle to call the variable correctly.

Here is the code to the small script:

```
#!/bin/bash


read -p "Datum eingeben: " date

datum=$(date -d 'TZ="UTC" $date' +%s)
echo $datum
```

I've tried different "quotations" trying to pass the variable correctly, but it either gets detected as a command, or as a invalid date.

Current Error message is:

date: invalid date ‘TZ="UTC" $date’

I've tried changing the quotation to different styles, but got none to work.

Tried to give it a set date and that worked perfectly fine.

Comment: I am not sure UTC is a timezone, as it represents universal time (so, no timezone, obviously). Moreover, why rebuild a scheduler when you already have so many of them out there, and probably have access to cron ?

Comment: You may want to say `datum=$(TZ="UTC" date -d "$date" +%s)`.

Comment: (1) Variables are not expanded between single quotes. Therefore `'TZ="UTC" $date'` does not make sense. (2) See _man date_ on how to specify the time zone, when you want to do it  in the `-d` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

@Zimon, With all the respect to the comments, and to summarize, I believe this would do the job for you.

##### Details

- Although it works, I'd recommend using user-defined variable names to avoid confusion such as `_date` to differ from the `date` command.
- Since you are using `+%s` and from the `date` man page it is calculating the seconds "seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" based on your provided date & time. So if you still think you need to mention it just add `TZ=UTC` to the left side of the `date` command - so it will be evaluated only for that command.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Datum eingeben: " _date

datum=$(TZ='UTC' date -d "$_date" +%s)

echo $datum
```

###### Bonus

If you need to include a parameter in double quotes where you already have outer double quotes, then you can escape the inner double quotes by a Backslash `\` character like in the following:

Suppose you need `date -d "$date somthingElse="$value"" +%s`

The currect syntax in BASH will be `date -d "$date somthingElse=\"$value\"" +%s`